# Angular NgFor in Form using Input in table

Tags: angular, model, binding, ngfor

So I am trying to implement list of ManualPolicies in a form.

and it seems to be showing only the last element of my list in my form.

While debugging I can see my 2 different policies. But not when the UI show's them.

Here is the HTML with what i use from Angular:

```
     <tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let mp of gdsPropertyConfigInfo.bookingPal_CancellationPolicy.manualPolicies; let i = index;">
        <td>
           <select id="{{i}}" class="form-control" id="ddMAnualPolicy" name="ddManualPolicy" aria-placeholder="Type..."
                              [(ngModel)]="gdsPropertyConfigInfo.bookingPal_CancellationPolicy.manualPolicies[i].manualPolicyType">
              <option *ngFor="let manualPolicyType of gdsPropertyConfigInfo.manualPolicyTypes" [value]="manualPolicyType">{{manualPolicyType}}</option>
           </select>
        </td>
        <td>
           <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtChargeValue" 
                            [(ngModel)]="mp.chargeValue" 
                            autocomplete="off" placeholder="Charge Value..." onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 49 && event.charCode <= 57'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtBeforeDays" [value]="mp.beforeDays" [(ngModel)]="mp.beforeDays" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Before Days..." onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 49 && event.charCode <= 57'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtCancellationFee" [(ngModel)]="mp.cancellationFee" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Cancellation Fee..." onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 49 && event.charCode <= 57'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span (click)="deleteManualPolicy(i)">
               <svg class="icon16 icon-orange">
                   <use xlink:href="assets/images/icons/sprite16.svg#icon-trash-2"></use>
               </svg>
            </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Would someone be able to help me out,

Here it is:

```
{
"cancellationPolicyType": "MANUAL",
"manualPolicies": [
    {
        "manualPolicyType": "PERCENTAGE",
        "chargeValue": 423,
        "beforeDays": 423,
        "cancellationFee": 324
    },
    {
        "manualPolicyType": "FLAT",
        "chargeValue": 456,
        "beforeDays": 567,
        "cancellationFee": 123567
    }
]}
```

Regards, Frank

Comment: Could you just put:           {{ gdsPropertyConfigInfo?.bookingPal_CancellationPolicy | json }}             at the beggining of your HTML and show the result?

Comment: I added to response in the questions

Comment: Yes, sorry. I saw it before and try to run it in stackblitz...but I get errors and I didn't have time.. The thing is that your code looks good to me. Maybe if you can put your code as it is now in stackblitz (just the table working and loading that data) and share the link, someone could help you better, or even I could try it again tomorrow evening. Good luck!

Comment: I only changed where I put the json. one bot said my answer was not good enough.

Comment: I found the solution by Adding ngNoForm on the HTML tag form

Comment: Could you please try and edit your code so that it provides a minimal reproducible example?